# ascii-hex conversion in verilog

Tags: c, ascii, hex, verilog

I was looking for a Verilog function to convert my ASCII input strings to hexadecimal output. I am not sure if I can do it in C and club it with Verilog. So far, I was able to print the input ASCII strings as hex values by using:

```
printf("Hexadecimal Output for <CALL-ID>: ");
for(c = 0; c < strlen(callid); c++)
{
  printf("TO: %x ", callid[c]);
}
```

Is there a way to save the output in a text/csv file and make it accessible to my verilog code snippet?

Or please let me know if there is an easier way in Verilog itself?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you should avoid calling `strlen()` each time the loop iterates. `strlen()` is not an O(1) operation. You should instead do `size_t max = strlen(callid); for(c = 0; c < max; c++)`

Comment: @Chris: Your advice helps, but it's still silly. Instead change the loop condition from `c<strlen(callid)` to simply `callid[c]` and avoid calling `strlen` at all.

Comment: Are you trying to drive a verilog bus with ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output to a text file, you could do something like this:

```
static int string_to_hex_file(const char *filename, const char *string)
{
    FILE            *out;
    const char      *s;

    if((out = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
      return 0;

    fprintf(out, "\"%s\", ", string);
    for(s = string; *s; s++)
    {
        if(s != string)
            fprintf(out, ", ");
        fprintf(out, "0x%02x", (unsigned char) *s);
    }
    fprintf(out, "\n");

    fclose(out);
    return 1;
}
```

Sample output for `string == "this is a test"`:

```
"this is a test", 0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x61, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74
```

Error checking can of course be improved, and you will likely need to tweak the output formatting to suit your needs.